# How to split a String into array by Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of below type.

> [test1,3,(257,305,435,900)]

Now i want to split this string into array cell. like this one

```
term => 'test1', 
num => 3,
info => array{ [0]=> 275, [1]=> 435, [2]=> 900 }
```

can any one know a regular expression pattern for this string....thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$string = "[test1,3,(257,305,435,900)]";

preg_match_all('/\[(?P<term>\w+),(?P<num>\d+),\((?P<info>[\d,]+)\)\]/', $string, $out);

$results = array (
   'term' => $out['term'][0],
   'num'  => $out['num'][0],
   'info' => explode(',', $out['info'][0])
);

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: NB: `split()` emits `E_DEPRECATED`, use `explode()` instead. But +1, this works nicely.

Comment: Thanks @DaveRandom. Why is `split()` deprecated?

Comment: Thank your for your quick and accurate response, but actually my string data is in this form.....[test1,3,(257,305,435,900)] OR [test1,1,(673)] OR [test1,1,()].....i.e: want that regx work on this form.....once again thanks.

Comment: Because it is part of the `ereg` family of functions. I actually thought it was just an alias of `explode()` until I looked it up in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) but it seems this is not the case - I guess that comes from the fact that `join()` *is* an alias of `implode()`, and when you also write in Javascript it is easy to get them the wrong way round. I only discovered this myself when I [ran your code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UEe8Ti) and saw the error.

Comment: Now i fix this one...../\[(?P<term>\w+),(?P<num>\d+),\((?P<info>[\d,]*)\)\]/..... Only i change the last + to *.....hurah working perfect....

Comment: @ime.devdesks If you just replace the last `+` in the regex with a `*`, and change the line `'info' => explode(',', $out['info'][0])` to `'info' => ($out['info'][0]) ? explode(',', $out['info'][0]) : array()` then this will work for you.